# Tests work in shell, but not in Textmate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate

If I run rails' unit tests directly in Textmate, I get the following error:

`rake aborted! uninitialized constant Object::Bundler /Users/markus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2482:in const_missing' /Users/xxx/tickets/config/boot.rb:9:in rescue in ' /Users/xxx/tickets/config/boot.rb:5:in ' :29:in`require' :29:in `require' /Users/xxx/tickets/config/application.rb:1:in ' :29:in`require' :29:in `require' /Users/xxx/tickets/Rakefile:4:in ' /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in load' /Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-
[…]
Done`

If I run the tests in my shell with `rake test:units` everything is fine. What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have TM_Ruby and PATH within Advanced/Shell Variables in Textmate Pref?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have RVM then you should do this:

http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/textmate/

works like a charm.

Youre problem here is that your textmate environment doesn't find bundler, because it can't find your gemset folder.

If you follow the link above, everything should be fine.

Cheers,

Comment: This worked for me, specifically the part where it talked about changing the bundler Builder.rb that is built into TextMate.  Search that page for "Builder.rb"